# Xpages DbLookup and combo boxes

Tags: xpages

Is it possible at all, in XPages, to have 3 combo boxes that are dependant from one another?

Let's say I have Province/State, City, StreetName:  what do I need to have the StreetName drop down display values form the selected Province and City?

I tried with a categorized view, a flat view, but I can't get it to work.  Is it that the DbLookup "key" can only be a string and not an array of strings?

This is what I tried:

```
@DbLookup(@DbName(), "v2Flat", ["MyProv","MyCity"], "StreetName")
```

that is using a flat view: returns all the street names, regardless of the selected city

```
@DbLookup(@DbName(), "v2Categorized", ["MyProv","MyCity"], "StreetName")
```

that is using a categorized view (StateProv, City as categories): returns only the first street name for the selected Prov/City.

All the fields are in a panel that is refreshed when first 2 combo boxes are changed (I know it works as the values listed in the street name combo change as well).

Am I wrong to think that an array can be used in a DbLookup???

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ben, not sure the @function implements using an array as a key, at least, I never got it to work.

Just use the Domino view object and getAllEntriesByKey

```
var linksView:NotesView = session.getCurrentDatabase().getView("myview");
var search = new java.util.Vector();
search.add("Checksheet");
search.add("APQP");
var entryCol:NotesViewEntryCollection = linksView.getAllEntriesByKey(search, true);
```

Then loop through entryCol and get what you need and add to an array one at a time.

Howard

Comment: Howard, 

While thinking of an alternate way of acheiving this, I thought it was either the solution you proposed or a to create a new view, with the first categorized column being a comniation of the first 2 keys, and use that second view in the third combobox...

I needed the thing to work ASAP for demo purposes, so I went with the view as it was faster to code, but I will change that to use what you suggested before going to production, for sure.

Comment: If another view was a possibility that approach might be better from a performance point of view. It depends on how many items were in the view. My code walks through all the view entries, so that might be an expensive operation for a big view. But, in either case, my previous analysis of "@"functions vs. using the Domino objects showed me that the "@"functions to lookup data were very slow.

Comment: I was planning on getting the first combobox values using a DbColumn, the second one with a DbLookup and to write a small SSJS function that would take the first 2 combobox values as params, so the SSJS code would not loop through that many documents since the getDocumentsByKeys would be quite specific.  Not sure wich one will be faster though...  I'll have to run some tests I guess  ;)      Oh, and the real thing has nothing to do with Streets for a specific city, so there won't be a lot of documents returned in SSJS (it has more to do with classification of documents using 3 levels).

Comment: Apparently, the SSJS getAllEntriesByKey doesn't work on a categorized view.  It works fine on a flat view but only returns the first value if the view is categorized.  Looks like I need that flat view anyway, so I'll stick with the DbLookup in the flat view   :/

Comment: Performance wise the SSJS getAllEntriesByKey is many times faster than DBlookup...